# Cygwin/X startx gives blank gray screen

Tags: cygwin

So I know I've had this working before, but after a fresh install of Windows XP and Cygwin, I can't seem to get the Cygwin/X server to give me anything other than a gray screen and an hourglass cursor. I followed the instructions on the Cygwin/X website. I haven't been able to find anything helpful via Google. Anyone here seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I sat down at my PC tonight to do more investigation, looked in my .xinitrc file and saw nothing of concern there, and ran startx again. Everything worked :-/  Go figure.

Thanks for looking, and to Kyle for answering.

Answer (score 1):

That is usually just the X Server running without any programs, such as a window manager...

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I had to install twm to get it to stop bitching at me. I can also see xterm running if I issue ps. What bugs me is that one would think that by following the instructions that things would just work, like they used to.